# Как в TextBox найти нужные символы?

Tags: c#, adb

Пишу прогу, которая работает вместе с adb.exe
Сделал так,чтобы все ответы от adb выводились в TextBox.
Создал процесс,который чекает устройства с включенной откладкой

```
Process checkDevices = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo checkDevicesProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
checkDevicesProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
checkDevicesProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
checkDevicesProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
checkDevicesProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
checkDevicesProcessInfo.FileName = "adb.exe";
checkDevicesProcessInfo.Arguments = " devices";
checkDevices.StartInfo = checkDevicesProcessInfo;
checkDevices.Start();
infoViewer.Text = checkDevices.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

В TextBox выводится информация типа:

```
List of devices attached
721Lxxxxxxxxxx            online
```

Так вот,нужно чтобы первые 4 символа считывались и сохранялись в переменную.Как это можно реализовать?

Хочу сделать определение модели телефона (а это можно сделать по первым цифрам и буквам).

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = TextBox.Text;
str = str.Substring(25,4);//Первое число - начальный индекс, второе - сколько символов копировать

Console.WriteLine (str);
```